# Unable to deploy to meteor.com (incompatible architecture error)

Tags: meteor

I am unable to deploy an app to meteor.com through the `meteor deploy` command. The command returns the following error:

`error: getstream:bin-deps is not compatible with architecture 'os.linux.x86_64'`

The dependency in question which relies on binary modules is [gestream:bin-deps](https://atmospherejs.com/getstream/bin-deps). I have made sure this package is built on all available platforms.

Is there any way to get more insight into the reason why the deploy fails? Trying to install the package on a 'os.linux.x86_64' machine works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, do that:

```
$ rm -Rf node_modules
$ rm -Rf .meteor/local
$ meteor 
??????
PROFIT!
```